# Symfony returning HTTP 304 locally, but HTTP 200 for matching ETag in production

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, http-caching

Due to a heavy API call taking upwards of 20 seconds, I have enabled computation of ETag for that resource and pre-compute the ETag before doing any heavy DB work to be able to return early. This works fine using the PHP development server (I can debug step through the code and see the HTTP status codes being correct) and I get HTTP 304, but for some reason it does not seem to take effect when deploying to production and I wonder how I can debug it?

The curl call sees the right `If-None-Match` ETag being sent, but still I get HTTP 200 and the same Etag back instead of HTTP 304.

```
> if-none-match: W/"5e3f549935516374f93531655b66aaf4"
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Mon, 10 Jan 2022 16:21:55 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< server: nginx
< cache-control: private
< etag: W/"5e3f549935516374f93531655b66aaf4"
```

As this works locally (using the Symfony development server: `./bin/console server:run`), but not when deploying to production, I suspect it is something to do with which `$kernel` is running, but I have followed the [caching guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html#caching-on-the-shoulders-of-giants) and changed both `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php` to include the following:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

// enable caching
// all authorized endpoints are automatically no-cache by default
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

---

The code in question looks something like this:

```
$computed = $this->getEtagAndTimestampForCatalogByUserAndType($user, $catalog_type);
$etag = $computed['etag'];
// Save the DB some work and avoid recomputing already here
if (self::matchingEtag($request, $etag)) {
    return $this->json(null, Response::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED);
}

// bla bla domain code
$responseData = doHeavyDBStuff();

$jsonResponse = $this->json($responseData);
$jsonResponse->setEtag($etag);

return $jsonResponse;
```

Since enabling the HttpCache class in Symfony removes all caching headers before they reach `AppKernel` using this "early-exit" is not usually possible, but I chose to use a little trick where I fetch the headers in `AppCache.php` and assign them to custom headers (`X-If-Modified-Since`) that I then can compare in my etag comparison above:

```
class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    const CUSTOM_IF_NONE_MATCH_HEADER = 'x-if_none_match';

    public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
    {
        /* Work around the fact that the caching layer removes the headers. This allows for custom caching strategies */
        $request->headers->add(array(AppCache::CUSTOM_IF_NONE_MATCH_HEADER => $request->headers->get('if_none_match')));
        return parent::handle($request, $type, $catch);
    }
```

---

In production this is running on

- PHP FPM behind Nginx.
- Symfony 3.4
- PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up debugging this step-by-step through HttpCache and found this is actually [issue #37948 on the Symfony tracker](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37948) which *attempted* to fix less than a year ago, in [March 2021](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/40545).

Some browsers add the `W/` (weak) prefix to the etags and Symfony did not handle this at all. So typically it sets `Etag: "foo"` on the response and it was unable to see that this was the same as the etag in `If-None-Match: W/"foo"` coming from the browser, unlike what the RFC spec says it should.

So to make this work for my needs, I actually needed to hand-parse the etags in my controller code to patch the logic. That's what I get for not upgrading, I guess :) The patching code can be found in the [Response.php code for Symfony 4.4](https://github.com/thunder/symfony/blob/b639fe644b5057fa1b103dcfa05f9fd5169942ba/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L1082-L1099).

This code is used by me and is basically the PR for Symfony 4.4 patched up to normalize the entity tags before comparison.

```
protected static function normalizeWeakComparitor($etag)
{
    if (self::isWeakComparitor($etag)) {
        return self::stripQuotes(substr($etag, 2));
    }
    return self::stripQuotes($etag);
}

protected static function isWeakComparitor($ifNoneMatchEtag): bool
{
    return 0 == strncmp($ifNoneMatchEtag, 'W/', 2);
}

protected static function stripQuotes($string)
{
    if (substr($string, 0, 1) == '"' && substr($string, -1) == '"') {
        return substr($string, 1, -1);
    }
    return $string;
}

/**
 * Manual matching code to handle a bug in the ETag code in Symfony <= 4.4
 * See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655974/symfony-returning-http-304-locally-but-http-200-for-matching-etag-in-production/70670045#70670045
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $etag
 * @return bool
 */
protected static function matchingEtag(Request $request, $etag): bool
{
    $notModified = false;
    $ifNoneMatchEtags = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $request->headers->get(\AppCache::CUSTOM_IF_NONE_MATCH_HEADER), null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    if ($ifNoneMatchEtags) {

        // Based on buggy patch to Symfony 4.4 I fixed up
        $etag = self::normalizeWeakComparitor($etag);

        // Use weak comparison as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-3.2.
        foreach ($ifNoneMatchEtags as $ifNoneMatchEtag) {
            $ifNoneMatchEtag = self::normalizeWeakComparitor($ifNoneMatchEtag);

            if ($ifNoneMatchEtag === $etag || '*' === $ifNoneMatchEtag) {
                $notModified = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $notModified;
}
```